# Simple Verticle and Horizontal CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, center

I am trying to make DIV verticle and horizontal center. I am using code from here : [How can I vertically center a div element for all browsers using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-can-i-vertically-center-a-div-element-for-all-browsers-using-css)

I tried both

```
display: grid;
place-items: center;
```

and

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

My code :

```css
body {
                background: #000000 50% 50%;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }
            
            .video {            
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
            }
```

```html
       <body> <div class="video">
  
            
                
<img src="https://place-hold.it/25x25" />

            </div> </body>
```

Horizontal center : Success

Vertical center : failed

with above two CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because elements by default have a height to `fit-content`. So you need to define a height higher then the `fit-content` height:

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.video {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/25x25" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So, adding height and width will fix with VH

Answer (score 1):

You can just add height as `100vh` in video class.

```css
body {
  background: #000000 50% 50%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.video {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/25x25" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should always add an explanation as code-only answers are hard to understand and considered low-quality.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the feedback. I'm kinda new here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `height: 100%;` to the div and all its ancestors (i.e. `body` and `html` in this case) for the flexbox centering method to work, otherwise it will only have the height of its contents (i.e. the image)  and not fill the viewport vertically.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: #000000 50% 50%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.video {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/25x25" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.video {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/25x25" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to center both vertically and horizontally, you can try this code below on your CSS:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/25x25" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Will not work. If you would have tested it yourself you would have seen that. You miss the most important detail.